# JavaScript function redirects to index page after execution MVC 5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm calling the function via

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "", null, new { onclick = "editshow('"+ item.vend_id + "','" + item.vend_name + "','" + item.vend_addr + "','" + item.vend_pno + "');" })
```

and the script is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function editshow(i, n, a, p) {
    document.getElementById("vid").value = i;
    document.getElementById("vnam").value = n;
    document.getElementById("vad").value = a;
    document.getElementById("vpno").value = p;


}
```

after its execution, it always redirects to the index page. How to stop it?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you intentionally left your `Action` name blank.

Since you do not want to hit the server when clicked, you should return a false from your javascript function.

```
    function editshow(i, n, a, p) {
      document.getElementById("vid").value = i;
      document.getElementById("vnam").value = n;
      document.getElementById("vad").value = a;
      document.getElementById("vpno").value = p;

      return false;
   }
```

If you do not return a `false` from a button click handler, most likely it will result in a `postback` behavior. In that case, it will go find the default page and in your case it probably is `index.cshtml`

Comment: yes that is exactly what I want to do, however tried your solution. Still redirecting.

Comment: @Bilalwcheema Look into your browser's developer console. You probably have a concatenation error, which can also result in a blank postback

Comment: Try not using @Html.ActionLink,just add a simple button / a with onclick function

Comment: @Bilalwcheema    In my point of view, you can redirect to the any of the action ,you want, by using  window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Edit", "Home")'; . So In this way also ,you avoid that redirect to the index page. Hope it helps. thanks

Comment: @KarthikElumalai can you write it?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Bilalcheema as discussed in the comment here is the answer

```
 function editshow(i, n, a, p) {
      document.getElementById("vid").value = i;
      document.getElementById("vnam").value = n;
      document.getElementById("vad").value = a;
      document.getElementById("vpno").value = p;

    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Edit", "Home")';
   }
```